# Interface Segregation Principle with "optional" methods in Implementation

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles, interface-segregation-principle

Interface Segregation Principle from SOLID says that Classes shouldn't have to implement/depend on methods they do not need. You should never have
`//Not used: just needed to implement interface` in the codebase.

How do I apply this principle when some methods are "optional" by their nature because the implementation class is a specific corner case.

Say I have this interface example:

```
Interface Input {
    Input create();
    void capitalizeInput(CAPITALIZATION cap);
    String getInput();
}

Class LatinInput implements Input {
    String input;
    Input create(String input){...}
    void capitalizeInput(CAPITALIZATION cap){...}
    String getInput(){...}
}

Class NumberOnlyInput implements Input {
    int input;
    Input create(int input){...}
    void capitalizeInput(CAPITALIZATION cap){
         // Needed because the interface requires it.
         return;
    }
    String getInput(){...}
}
```

That interface is used widely in the program by other classes. Currently in my programs I am doing something like the following.

```
Class B {
    Input input;
    B(Input input){
       this.input = input;
    }

    String doStuff(){
        ...
        methodA();
        ...
        methodB();
        ...
        methodC();
        ...
        methodA();
        ...
        return ...;
    }

    private void methodA(){
        ...
        input.transformInput(CAPITAL);
        input.getInput();
    }

    private void methodB(){
        ...
        input.getInput();
    }

    private void methodC(){
        ...
        input.transformInput();
    }
}
```

And it is called by a clas C;

```
Class C {
    void doStuff() {
        List<A> list = new Arraylist<>();
        list.add(LatinInput.create("hello"));
        list.add(LatinInput.create("goodbye"));
        list.add(NumberOnlyInput.create(12345));

        for(Input input: list){
            B b = new B(a);
            b.doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

How should I change the design to comply with ISP, without changing class C, while also not needing to check if the object is `instance of` during runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle):

> states that no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.

It doesn't say anything about implementing methods with empty body. Your class `B` uses both `capitalizeInput` and `getInput`, as long as those are only two methods in `Input`, it doesn't violate interface segregation principle. In your case `B` uses `NumberOnlyInput.capitalizeInput` it just so happens that empy body is a valid implementation of this functionality.

However, `Input.create` does violate ISP. `B` depends on `Input` but doesn't use `Input.create` - it is not called at all. In that case, you can just remove it from the interface.

You can still get rid of that strange empty method. Since `NumberOnlyInput` is special case of `LatinInput` you can reuse that class:

```
class NumberOnlyInput {
    static Input create(int input) {
        return new LatinInput(String.valueOf(input));
    }
}
```

It might be less clear or performant - which might be why special case for numbers was created in the first place.